# How can supervisord restart the npm start command successfully?

Tags: node.js, supervisord

I've started the "node start" via supervisord.

My problem is
Stopping / rebooting at supervisord will cause the node app.js process to remain without being killed

How can supervisord restart the npm start command successfully in this case?

supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:node]
command=npm start 
directory=/xx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
exitcodes=1
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "xxx
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me: change `npm start` to `node app.js` inside the Supervisor config file.

### Why?

I've noticed that using `npm start` starts two processes:

```
$ ps aux | grep node
ubuntu   19363  0.0  0.0   4508   708 ?        S    17:43   0:00 sh -c node index.js
ubuntu   19364  1.3  5.2 1041288 52996 ?       Sl   17:43   0:00 node index.js
```

And stopping it in Supervisor only stops the parent process:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl stop all
my_worker: stopped
$ ps aux | grep node
ubuntu   19364  0.3  5.2 1041288 52996 ?       Sl   17:43   0:00 node index.js
```

So putting `node index.js` directly in the supervisor config solved the problem for me.